# Component index vs classpath scanning in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring5

I was trying to upgrade myself to learn Spring5, and I read that it supports component index as an alternative to classpath scanning. I understand that the main benefit for implementing component index would be with the reduced startup time for large Spring projects.

Can someone here please explain more about what component index is and what advantages it offers over the classic classpath scanning?